# Grape + Cucumber | number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, ruby-grape

in my tests with cucumber I have a problem.

I'm getting a `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)` error when I try to make a request.

I make a request that is missing parameters, I should get a 400 error with the missing parameter message.

```rb
    params do
      requires :field_a, type: Integer
      requires :field_b, type: Integer
      requires :field_c, type: Float
      requires :field_d, type: Float
      optional :active, type: Boolean
    end
    post do
      result = Category.create_or_update(params)
      present result, with: Api::V1::Entities::CategoryObject
    end
```

so is my rescue_from:

```rb
  rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
      Rails.logger.debug(e)
      error!({ error: e.message, class: e.class.name, errors: e.errors }, e.status)
    end
```

Comment: on what line of code do you receive the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. inside the `Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors` return block, I had a Logger.debug. When doing an inspection of the running code, I noticed that there is something strange with the `Rails.Logger.debug` when the `ValidationErrors` object was sent. Then I realized that it was necessary to pass a "string" and not an object to be rendered.

```rb
# Before:
rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
      error = { error: e.message, class: e.class.name, errors: e.errors }

      Rails.logger.debug(e)

      Rack::Response.new(error.to_json, e.status)
end
```

```rb
# After:
rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
      error = { error: e.message, class: e.class.name, errors: e.errors }

      Rails.logger.debug(error.to_json) <----- HERE

      Rack::Response.new(error.to_json, e.status)
end
```